# form submit conflict with captcha

Tags: javascript, php, html

Php simple code to "protect" content.

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>

// protected content \\

<?php } else { ?>

<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="submit">click to view protected content</button>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Now i try add captcha when i click in submit button... 
but when i resolve captcha dont redirect for hide content

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdVvYQUAAAAAIVD_yRB8nBeajeEChQjXhhSldHj" type="submit" name="submit">view protected content</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add below JS

```
<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("your-form").submit();
}
</script>
```

And remember to change your form to

```
<form action="" method="post" id="your-form">
    <button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdVvYQUAAAAAIVD_yRB8nBeajeEChQjXhhSldHj" name="submit" data-callback="onSubmit">view protected content</button>
</form>
```